# How do can I use this reload() method to the onLongClick method?

Tags: java, android, notifydatasetchanged, onlongclicklistener

I am applying a delete function to my notes app, but when I delete something, it doesnt changes on the screen until I do some action that reloads it, like creating a new note, or accesing a note and the exiting it (even the one deleted). Only then, the deleted note will disappear, even though I clearly used the reload function. Here is my adapter, where I have the problem.

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder> {
public static class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout containerView;
    public TextView nameTextView;
    public NotesAdapter adapter = new NotesAdapter();

    public NoteViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.containerView = view.findViewById(R.id.note_row);
        this.nameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.note_row_name);

        this.containerView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View view) {
                final Note note = (Note) containerView.getTag();

                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.delete) {
                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Note deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            MainActivity.database.noteDao().delete(note.id);
                            adapter.reload;
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu);
                popupMenu.show();

                return true;
            }
        });

        this.containerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Note note = (Note) containerView.getTag();
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NoteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", note.id);
                intent.putExtra("content", note.content);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.note_row, parent, false);

    return new NoteViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NoteViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Note current = notes.get(position);
    holder.containerView.setTag(current);
    holder.nameTextView.setText(current.content);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notes.size();
}

public void reload() {
    notes = MainActivity.database.noteDao().getAll();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Please help me, I ve working on this for days now, and I am stuck at a simple problem

Comment: I would suggest you to use observer pattern for your requirement, that would help you massive way. Another way you can try out notifyDataChanged after deleting that would refresh your screen

Comment: But I cant use `notifyDataSetChanged` inside the method.

Comment: Why? what restricting to use?. Could you please post error message?

Comment: It just doesn't let me. It says that it doesnt recognize the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload data after the database has been updated. Invoke `reload()` after deleting a note:

```
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.delete) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Note deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MainActivity.database.noteDao().delete(note.id);
            reload(); // reload data
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had to do the NoteViewHolder non-static and that worked!